# Fuzzy, Wildcard search with multiple terms: Putting all data into one property?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, fuzzy-search, elasticsearch-5

I'm currently embedding Elasticsearch as a Search-Interface into an existing application.
The application is a classical 3-tier-application with a oracle SQL database.

I have the Entity 'Person' (database table), with the following attributes:

- first Name
- last Name
- full name (contains first name and last name concatenated)
- person-Nr.
- company Name
- A list of addresses with: street, zipcode, city, phone and email.

So far, I put it 1:1 into elasticsearch, for every db-column a property in elasticsearch.
Synchronisation and full-load of the data is no problem. But I'm struggling providing a "good" search experience, as there are many different things to pay attention to:

- Fuzzy Search (tolerance of one or two edit distance)
- Wildcard search (if I type "Ange", it should also find results with "Angelina")
- E-Mail-Address search (I'm already using `uax_url_email` tokenizer in combination with the `keyword` datatype)

As far as I can tell, `multi_match`, type `cross_fields` would be a good choice, but it can't do fuzzy-search and wildcard. type `best_fields` is also no option, because it can't do wildcard-search (as far as I know?). `most_fields` is also not suited and `phrase matching` can't do fuzziness.

Because of that, I'm currently using `simple_query_string`, example:

In the search field, I enter `Tom fisher`:
The query in `simple_query_string` is:

```
(tom* | tom~1)+(fisher* | fisher~1)
```

My question now is, would it be a bad idea, to just have on field "entity_content", which contains the content of all fields? This would be like as I had a .txt document with all information about the person.

- What are the advantages/disadvantages?

Answer (score 0):

By default Elastic had `_all` field, which is already catch-all field, e.g. all the information is stored into this field, without respect of where it comes from.

> The _all field can be useful, especially when exploring new data using
>   simple filtering. However, by concatenating field values into one big
>   string, the _all field loses the distinction between short fields
>   (more relevant) and long fields (less relevant). For use cases where
>   search relevance is important, it is better to query individual fields
>   specifically.
>
> The _all field is not free: it requires extra CPU cycles and uses more
>   disk space. If not needed, it can be completely disabled or customised
>   on a per-field basis.